# Validate that at least 1 checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have search for the same question, and I saw a few of the similar post, however my Userform still can't work. I am new to VBA and Userform.

I have a total of 12 Checkboxes (12 Months), and I have to check that at least one of the CheckBox is checked.

```
Dim atLeastOneChecked As Boolean
atLeastOneChecked = False
Dim ctrlNCK As Control
For Each ctrlNCK In Controls
    If TypeName(ctrlNCK) = "chkMonth" Then
        If ctrlNCK.Value = True Then atLeastOneChecked = True
    End If
Next ctrlNCK

If Not atLeastOneChecked = True Then
    MsgBox "Month cannot be empty.", vbExclamation, "Input Data"
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: When you say "can't work" do you mean that it always returns False?

Comment: Yes. It always return False, the `MsgBox` will keep pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but try:

```
If Left(ctrlNCK.Name,8) = "chkMonth" Then
```

I wouldn't ever expect the Type to be "chkMonth". This assumes that each relevant `CheckBox` name starts with "chkMonth".

If you only ever want one, and only one, month chosen, I'd consider using `OptionButtons` in a `Frame`.

Comment: You might try `If InStr(ctrlNCK.Name,"chkMonth")=1 Then` to avoid errors for controls with names shorter than 8 characters.

Comment: @Excellll, I don't think it causes an error. For example `? left("a",8)` in the Immediate Window yields "a". And from Excel 2010 Help, there's this:  "If greater than or equal to the number of characters in string, the entire string is returned."

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks for your answers! It works :) All my `CheckBox` name start with `"chkMonth"`, I named it `"chkMonth01" ... "chkMonth12"`. And I want user be able to select more then 1 month, therefore I used `CheckBox`. Can I ask you, is only `OptionButton` used in `Frame`? Or `CheckBox` can be use in `Frame` as well?

Comment: I'm glad it works. You can put other controls, including `CheckBoxes` in `Frames`. They can be handy for grouping controls, both visually and in your code. With `OptionButtons` they have the special characteristic that only one in the Frame can be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (chbindian + chbchinies + chbitalian + chbsindian) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Please select at least Two checkbox"
Exit Sub
End If
```

try this

`(chbindian + chbchinies + chbitalian + chbsindian)` replace this names with your checkbox name

Answer (score 0):

Using similar approach to the question code I came up with this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim chk As Control
Dim i As Long

For Each chk In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf chk Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        If chk = 0 Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
    If i = 12 Then
        MsgBox "Please select at least one month!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

MsgBox "You selected at least one month!"

End Sub
```

**To explain:**

The `For` loop is checking one by one each `CheckBox` on the `UserForm`.

If the value of the `CheckBox` is 0 (False) then the counter which is the `i` variable equals it's own value at the end of the previous iteration (current value) + 1.

Each `CheckBox` with a value of 0 (False) meaning it's 'unchecked' adds 1 to the counter and thus, once the loop is complete `i` will equal anywhere between 0 (all CheckBoxes are checked) and 12 (no CheckBoxes are checked).

After the loop is exited the next `if` statement checks if the value of the counter `i` is equal to 12 then a `MsgBox` displays `"Please select at least one month!"` otherwise whatever is meant to happen next will now execute (In my example its another `MsgBox` advising `"You selected at least one month!"`).

**NOTE:** If more CheckBoxes were added to the `UserForm` at a later time for whatever reason, my solution would be flawed as it will check *ALL* `CheckBox` commands on the form.

To work around that you can put the required `CheckBoxes` on a `Frame` on the `UserForm`.

Assuming the `Frame` is named `Frame1` all you would need to do is adjust the `For` line to specify for each `CheckBox` in `Frame1` on the `UserForm` like so: `For Each chk In Me.Frame1.Controls`